# variable echoing out the last of 3 numbers

Tags: php, web, numbers, screen-scraping, forward

Hi so I've currently got a output echoing 176 8 58 from a web scraping script. I want to pack this script up into a variable and echo it out in other places on the website.

I've packed this up by doing this

```
ob_start();
echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
$thenumbers = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

but when I echo it out like this

Now on the website the numbers are in spans and are split up by "/" do I need to do anything fancy? I'm kind of new to PHP so let me know if its something stupid!

```
<?php echo $thenumbers ?>
```

my output is then 176 8 58

Would really appreciate a bit of help

*(web scraping script i'm using had to hide the website i'm scraping as its in development)*

```
<?php
$teamlink = rwmb_meta( 'WEBSITE_HIDDEN' );

$arr = array( $teamlink ); 

foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. $value;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $elements = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'table')]/tr[3]/td[3]/span");

    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                ob_start();
                echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
                $win_loss = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

p.s I know the script works as its currently outputting standard text fine.

Comment: You have an extra `}`, is that a copying error?

Comment: Hi Barmar, Where are you seeing this?

Comment: NM, I didn't see one of the `foreach` statements because of the bad indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apoligies if I have completely misunderstood your question.

If you want to add a "/" between the numbers, where the spaces are you could:

```
 echo str_replace(' ','/',$thenumbers);
```

If you just want to show the last 3 digits (cleaning out the spaces from the string) you could;

```
 echo substr(str_replace(' ','',$thenumbers),-3);
```

Comment: That's everything except the first 3 digits, last 3 is `-3`.

Comment: Basicly the webscrape has output me the numbers 176 8 58 after using 

echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";. 

The issue is now I need to wrap those numbers up as a variable and echo them out in other places. 

So I've tried 

ob_start();
echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
$thenumbers = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

When I then echo out $thenumbers I just get the number 58

Comment: Wny don't you just assign directly to the variable? `$thenumbers .= $node->nodeValue;`

Comment: Well good news is Barmar has managed to get all the numbers to echo out. I didn't have the .= However now the numbers have echoed out as 176858 and I need to add / between them

Comment: Well.. so then do `$thenumbers .= $node->nodeValue.'/';` To get rid of the last "/" you can do `substr($thenumbers,0,-1);`